# Maven and JSF: Dependency with native code

Tags: java, jsf, maven

I have a JavaServer Faces project set up with maven and I have a dependency with native code.
The problem is, that only one instance of the app can exist, as the native library would be loaded by a different classloader otherwise. (This also makes it impossible to redeploy the application, which means you have to restart the web-server [glassfish in this case] each time)

How can I set up the dependency in a way that allows multiple instances?

As far as I can tell, the library needs to be loaded by the system classloader, but I do not see how that is possible.

I hope you can help me with this; it slows down development quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work, although it is quite an ugly hack.

I add the classpath of the application classloader to the system classloader (using reflection) and load the library in there.

I then use a delegate driver to load the real driver, as the DriverManager is not able to load JDBCs from other classloaders.

(I forgot to mention that it is the sqlite connector)

If you find a better solution, please tell me. I have to admit, I am not satisfied with this approach.